# Including C file in header file

Tags: c, header-files

Is it correct to include a C file in an header file? An example:

**myheader.h**

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H
 #define MYHEADER_H

 #include <stdio.h>

 void foo();

 #include "myfile.c"

#endif // MYHEADER_H
```

**myfile.c**

```
#include "myheader.h"

void foo()
{
    puts("I'm foo!!");
}
```

With that I can compile with `gcc -o main main.c` instead of `gcc -o main main.c myfile.c`, where main uses `foo()`.

Comment: It's not correct, May I ask why would you want to do it the wrong way?

Comment: "With that I can compile" -> well then, that's your on-topic answer.

Comment: @iharob I didn't know it was wrong.

Comment: @SimoneBonato No, it's a valid question. I am just wondering why did you want to do it?

Comment: Part of knowing C is to know how to write understandable code. C will not complain if you include .c files or whatever extension you fancy. This is not a reason to do it. If you write C for fun and alone, do whatever you want. If you plan on working together with other programmers one day, just don't.

Comment: @iharob It's a stupid thing: I use Code::Blocks IDE and I don't know how to compile with other files e.g. `gcc -o main main.c myfile.c` and in general I find `gcc -o main main.c` more convenient.

Comment: @SimoneBonato If you migrate to Linux and learn Makefiles and eventually autotools you would never go back to codeblocks and suffer with the difficult way things are when you must use a GUI for everything.

Comment: @iharob I use Linux. Ubuntu with XFCE precisely.

Comment: Why my question is -1? Is it stupid?

Answer (score 4):

It's legal, but this doesn't mean it's a good practice.

Compilation is done through translation units which are independently compiled from a single source file into an object file.

Later all of these translation units are linked together to produce the final binary file.

Now, this allows you to hide inside the source files things that should be local to that source file only (which includes local types and being protected against name clashes) which means also that you will expose only what is really meant to be exposed through header files.

This is a good way to manage encapsulation and keep code maintainable, so yes you can do it but you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

It's legal but it is very bad practice.

The common and good practice to do is to include "header files" with extension .h and put inside them only "extern" function declarations (and the "ugly" global variables declarations if you use them) and type declarations.

In your source file .c you put external functions definitions (and external variable initialization) along with static functions. It makes sense with the convention to generate one object file (.o or .obj) per source file.

If you put an extern function definition in a header and include it in two different source files you will get an error when linking (last step generating an executable). If you do the same with a static function, the function will be effectively defined once in each object file, it will work but it won't be optimized at all.

Per convention we use the "extern" specifier only in headers for extern function declaration and we put no specifier in source file (extern is the default, if you don't specify "static", then function is extern).

Comment: It's legal and it's correct are quite different things.

Comment: @iharob I changed the term as you seem to believe my sentence could be wrongly interpreted.